# Dynamically updating config data codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, config

I have created my custom config file to store information about site such as if it is online or offline like-vice.

For that I have created new file in config folder and stores default values in global $config[] array with my own index.

I want to update these config data dynamically with admins control eg. he can select to put site in offline mode.

For that I have used function

```
$this->config->set_item('config_array_index','value_to_set');
```

but, I don't know why it is not working for me ?

I am not able to see any update in my config file. Also I am autoloading my config file.
Am I missing something?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Setting a config item only applies to the current session - it does not overwrite your actually codeigniter files.

If you want to permanetly take a site offline, your'll need some sort of persistant storage, such as a value in a database that is checked/updated as needed

Comment: Thank you, this helped me figure out where to go next with a project of mine quite well.

Answer (score 1):

you can create an empty config file, within your config directory , and then append your data to it using a functionality like fwrite ( you can check for some other CI function to use ).
and add it to your autoload file .